# How many tag Badges are there?

Tags: support, tag-badges

I saw [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and [List of Badges with Full Description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/210108).

I [earned](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/291/android?userid=1318946) the [android bronze badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/291/android) which has following description.

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki
>   answers in the **android** tag.

I have doubt that if any one create any tag then it will also rewarded as badge if they **`score 100 for at least 20 non-community wiki answer on that tag.`**

So there are how many total number of badges currently?

Comment: your doubt is wrong. If a tag is created and someone earns enough rep in the tag, they will get the tag badge. The posts you linked describe the non-tag badges. In addition to those there are bronze gold and silver tag badges available for each tag. The "with full description" question explains tag badges in an answer and notes "•A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges."

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your reply. So Its like that there are infinite badges?

Comment: At this moment in time? No, the number of currently available badges can be counted (standard badges + (tags `x` 3)). But as there is no limit to the number of tags that can be created, yes, the number of badges available is infinite.

Comment: Also, tag badges are created only when there is x no. of questions in that tag (don't remember the exact number). So, the calculation is a bit more trickier.

Comment: @JonW Technically there is a limit, because tags have an upper bound of 25 characters and there are limited number of characters, at least no more than 100, so 100^25+100^24+...<10^51 tags at most if I'm generous. However, one can always score more nice answer badges.

Comment: @wythagoras haha, well 'technically correct' *is* the best type of correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tag badges do not have a limit - they are being generated "on the fly", dynamically, based on score of users in the tags.

You can see the total amount of awarded tag badges at any given time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> [image]

To see how many distinct tag badges exist, you can go to each of the three pages, e.g. [bronze tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze), and using a browser search find how many, e.g. searching for "Earn at least 100 total score" tells that at this  point there are 3519 different bronze tag badges.

We can also use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to find those stats, however the data in there won't be live. (up to week old)
There is already [other answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272469/152859) with such  a query.

Answer (score 4):

You can have an exact number of badges, both tag based and system defined by running [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/420315) for the site you're interested in:

```sql
with uni_badge as (
select name
     , tagbased
     , count(*) as [number of badges]
from badges
group by name
, tagbased
)
select 1 as id
     , 'Grand total' as [name]
     , 0 as [tagbased]
     , count(*) as [number of badges]
from uni_badge
union
select 2
     , 'all badges' as [name]
     , 0 as [tagbased]
     , count(*) as [number of badges]
from uni_badge
where tagbased = 0
union
select 3
     , 'all tagbased'
     , 1 as [tagbased]
     , count(*) as [number of badges]
from uni_badge
where tagbased = 1
union
select row_number() over(order by [number of badges] desc) + 3 
     , name
     , tagbased
     ,[number of badges]
from uni_badge
order by 1
```

At the day of posting this is the outcome:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, 3515 vs. 3519 now - four new tag badges since Monday? :-)